# Separate Undo manager stacks for different modes within same window in mac app

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, undo-redo, nsundomanager

I have developed a mac application where different modes are active at different point of times and undo manager has to be implemented separately for each mode.But the root viewController is the same and only top view's undo stack should be active.

For example: I have an application named homeViewController(VC1) and i have different mode in popoverViewController(VC2) - when VC2 is active and `cmd+z` is pressed only VC2 operations should be undone and VC1 undo stack should not be affected.

Whereas, now though i have registered using VC2 once the VC2 undoStack is empty VC1 undoStack is accessed and performed.

For better understanding --> [demo ios app](https://github.com/tomkowz/undo-manager-practice) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Pk85X8bugk&feature=youtu.be), [article](http://szulctomasz.com/blog/2015-09-13-ios-undo-and-redo-with-nsundomanager/)). Similar implementation in **mac app** did not behave as expected. I want the same exact working for *mac app*. Is it possible?

I am wondering if NestedUndoGroup or undoGrouping can help me in any way!!

Can anyone please help me how to have separate undo stacks for each view controller?

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Seperate undo stacks = seperate undo managers.

Comment: but within same window though i create separate undo managers it refers to the same stack in AppKit

Comment: No, each instance of `NSUndoManager` has its own stack.

Comment: yes but when the undoManager2 is done with its stack cmd+z automatically gets the undo action from undoManager1 which is not the desirable behaviour for me. I want the undo to get disabled once the stack2 is empty. I hope you got my point

Comment: Add your code to the question please.